# What was the reason that my header section for php mail function was not working

Tags: php, email, joomla, sendmail

My previous header section was.

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . '\r\n';
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . '\r\n';
$headers .= 'To:   <abc@gmail.com>' . '\r\n';
$headers .= 'From: xyz <info@gmail.com>' . '\r\n' . 'Return-Path: info@gmail.com \n' . 'Reply-To: info@gmail.com \n';
```

And I replaced above with this : Which is working for me.

```
$headers = "From: xyz<info@gmail.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: xyz<info@gmail.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Now my question is :
1. What the reason that my old code was working fine previously and 
2. What is technical difference b/w my old and new header section ?

Comment: you can see difference why from and reply after mime header? and proper spacing and quotes

Answer (score 0):

Note the difference between `'\r\n'`  and `"\r\n"`.

Double quotes are a requirement for line breaks. If you use single quote, they will be treated as actual text and thus won't work properly

Comment: Dont know, I just found this now, but I'm sure it was working.